# Google credential fails to refresh token with email and profile scope

Tags: google-plus, google-oauth, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

I'm using a google credential as part of the google-api-client. I'm attempting to get their email and profile using the Plus api with the `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me` endpoint. Documentation states that you can pass it the `email` and `profile` scopes and it should return the information. Though all I get is

> "code": 403,
>   
> "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."

Though when I use the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` and the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile` scope the call works just fine.

Building the credential as:
`GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
                .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                .setServiceAccountId(accountId)
                .setServiceAccountScopes(accountScopes)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKey(accountPrivateKey)
                .setServiceAccountUser(accountUser)
                .build();`
And the `googleCredential.refreshToken()` call fails.

Comment: It looks like there is a problem getting the credentials, not using them. Is this a marketplace app? If so, there is an open issue where the new email and profile scopes can't be added to the Google Apps Marketplace configuration.

Comment: @EricKoleda Yea, I believe you are right, the problem is getting the access tokens. Is there any word of a fix for this, being the deadline of OAuth1 support, and certain endpoints/apis is approaching.